# FirebaseMessagingService onNewToken() is called but not onMessageReceived()

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I know that this question has been asked many times and answered, my issue has to do with Firebase Console telling me that my app never communicated with their servers even when my app successfully receives the registration token.

When I uninstall and reinstall my app, it does invoke onNewToken() method of FirebaseMessagingService class (or rather the class that extends from it).

Even FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId() works fine and fetches the token.

But since firebase console says that the app never communicated with their servers, when I send a notification from the console, it does not reach my phone. At least, onMessageReceived() never gets called.

I do not know if there is a way to filter logcat to find out if a notification was indeed received by the phone and that there is something else wrong in my set up. If you know of such a way, that would help too.

In any case, if you have any suggestion, I would highly appreciate that. I have tried to send notifications with/without data from the console. I even tried to send to a topic and made the app subscribe to the topic. Yet, onMessageReceived() did not get called and notification did not get displayed. Quite frustrated. Please help.

app/build.gradle has:

```
dependecies {
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.0.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

project/build.gradle has:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you also include the intent filter into your manifest? Like this:

```
<service
    android:name=".FirebaseServiceClassName"
    android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```